# the difference between the two ways to pass enviament variable to webpack config?

Tags: webpack

1. cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack
2. webpack -env.foo=bar

Like showed above,we have two ways to pass variables to `webpack` config from cli.
But,what is the advantages and faults of the two ways?What situation should I use the first way,and the second?

Answer (score 1):

Things like `NODE_ENV` is a generic environment variable. This means that it is accessible to any code, not just webpack. In particular, the `NODE_ENV` is used when you need to relay the environment type to code that is not going to use webpack-specific APIs (like the `env` object). One caveat of using this is that it's not cross-platform, in the sense that different platforms may use different syntax for setting environment variables (unless you use helpers like `cross-env`).

The [`--env` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) is webpack-specific, so it's only available to the code that webpack makes `env` object available to. This is usually good for usage within webpack config or for setting environment variables from within webpack config modules when you want cross-platform support. Usually this is done in conjunction with the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_ENV=production webpack` - you just create a variable in your console and then try to access to this variable from Node.js through process object, so this variable is not a part of Node.js process.

`webpack --env.foo=bar` - you pass a variable directly to node.js process, so you can access it directly like env.foo.

The first way is good for passing global variables like environment, the second way - for other stuff, e.g. --env.email=bar